# Latest stable release (v1.1.1) - The built-in library 'dart:io' is not available on Dartium

Tags: dart, chromium, dart-polymer, dartium

My application was working mint until I just updated to the latest version of the Dart SDK and Editor.

When I run the app in Dartium, an error is thrown `'The built-in library 'dart:io' is not available on Dartium'`. I am not using dart:io directly but imported lib packages like google_oauth2_client use it. This was all working fine until just an hour or two ago.

I am sort of stuck until this is resolved. Is anyone having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

dart:io isn't compatible with the browser, it's standalone-VM only. If google_oauth2_client uses it, which I doubt the library were not intended for client usage. Have you tried `pub upgrade`?

Comment: I saw a discussion recently in the Dart Google gropu about a bug in the versioning of some packages (in relation to agrs AFAIR) that caused this problem. Probably fixed by now. Just run `pub upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

google_oauth2_client has both a browser library and a console library. The console library makes use of dart:io while the browser one does not. Make sure that you are using the browser version. You can see an [example](https://github.com/dart-gde/dart-google-oauth2-library/tree/master/example) of how to do this.